# How to get the name of the class that was called

Tags: jquery, class

I have two `<div>`s with different class names on my Header menu:

```
<div class="header lorem menu right"><a>Lorem</a></div>
<div class="header ipsum menu right"><a>Ipsum</a></div>
```

And i want to copy those `<div>`s contents

```
<a>Lorem</a>
<a>Ipsum</a>
```

and append to my Footer menu:

```
<div class="footer lorem menu right"></div>
<div class="footer ipsum menu right"></div>
```

I could do this using the following functions:

```
$('.footer.lorem').append($('header.lorem').html());
$('.footer.ipsum').append($('header.ipsum').html());
```

But I would like to make this function an automated way, so I could call Eg:

```
$('.lorem').each(function(){
   $('.footer' + THE-NAME-CALLED).append($('.header' + THE-NAME-CALLED).html());
});
```

So doing this way I can use the same function for multiple classes Eg:

```
$('.lorem, .ipsum, .dolor, .sit, .amet').each(function(){
   $('.footer' + THE-NAME-CALLED).append($('.header' + THE-NAME-CALLED).html());
});
```

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: `$(this).attr('class')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this should work:

```
$.each(['.lorem', '.ipsum', '.dolor', '.sit', '.amet'], function(i, value) {
     $('.footer' + value).append($('.header' + value).html());
});
```

Comment: dear, I need again your help. How should I do if I wanted to use with the 'click' function? For example, If I click on 'header lorem', the 'footer lorem' hides - If I click the 'header ipsum' hides 'footer ipsum'. Is to do this in a similar way? thank you.

Comment: Do you want the same thing to happen for clicks on the footer? For instance if you click on .footer.lorem, then .header.lorem hides?

Comment: Not exactly, only one will be clickable. Suppose, when I click '.menu.lorem', hides'.window.loren'. When I click '.menu.ipsun' hides '.window.ipsum' when I click '.menu.dolor' hides '.window.dolor' ... and so on...

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
$.each(['.lorem', '.ipsum'], function(_, cls) {
    var $src = $('.header').filter(cls);
    var $dst = $('.footer').filter(cls);
    $src.clone().appendTo($dst);
});
```

For efficiency one could also move the `$('.header')` and `$('.footer')` jQuery object evaluations to outside the loop:

```
var $header = $('.header');
var $footer = $('.footer');
$.each(['.lorem', '.ipsum'], function(_, cls) {
    var $src = $header.filter(cls);
    var $dst = $footer.filter(cls);
    $src.clone().appendTo($dst);
});
```

Note that it's generally bad practise to use serialisation (`.html`) and de-serialisation to copy elements around.  It destroys any event handlers or other data attached to those elements.  The `.clone` method instead works directly on the DOM nodes and not on their serialised format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `.header` and `.footer` `div` elements follow the same order when being copied, you can use the `index`:

```
$('.header').each(function() {
    var $header = $(this);
    $('.footer').eq($header.index()).text($header.text());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/LUUbD/)